# Scrapy Spider: Stuck with callback not firing

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a [github repo](https://github.com/orgs/COST-ELTeC/repositories).

I want to extract all XML file urls at level1 of every repo and in the best case also extract information from the XML files.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


repo_rule = Rule(
    LinkExtractor(
        restrict_xpaths="//a[@itemprop='name codeRepository']",
        restrict_text=r"ELTeC-.+"
    )
)

pagination_rule = Rule(
    LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='next_page']")
)

level_rule = Rule(
    LinkExtractor(allow=r"/level1"),
    follow=True,
    callback="parse_level"
)


class ELTecSpider(CrawlSpider):
    """Scrapy CrawlSpider for crawling the ELTec repo."""

    name = "eltec"
    start_urls = ["https://github.com/orgs/COST-ELTeC/repositories"]

    rules = [
        repo_rule,
        pagination_rule,
        level_rule,
    ]

    def parse_level(self, response):
        print("INFO: ", response.url)



process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings={
        "FEEDS": {
            "items.json": {
                "format": "json",
                "overwrite": True
            },
        },
    }
)

process.crawl(ELTecSpider)
process.start()
```

The above extracts the responses for all level1 folders, but somehow I am stuck at this point. My plan was to go down every level1 url using callbacks like so:

```
def parse_level(self, response):
    yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_docs)

def parse_docs(self, response):
    docs_urls = response.xpath("//a[@class='Link--primary']")

    for url in docs_urls:
        print("INFO: ", url)
```

But apparently the callback never even fires.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to put `print()` at the beginning of `parse_docs()`? Maybe it executes your callback but maybe `xpath`doesn't find elements and it doesn't run `for`-loop with `print()`.

Comment: I'm not sure but `scrapy` may remember visited pages and skip scraping the same url - this way it doesn't waste time to get the same page again, and it also prevents infinite loop. When you run `scrapy.Request(response.url, ...)` you try to scrape the same again and `scrapy` and it can skip it. If you need to scrape the same page again then you may need `Request(..., dont_filter=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrapy` remembers visited pages and it skips scraping the same `url` again.
This way it doesn't waste time to get the same page again, and it also prevents crawling loops.

When you run `scrapy.Request(response.url, ...)` then you try to scrape the same `url` again and `scrapy` skips it.

If you really need to scrape the same page again then you may need

```
Request(..., dont_filter=True)
```

(Doc: [scrapy.http.Request](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request))

---

I would rather run directly

```
yield self.parse_docs(response)
```

---

There is another problem inside `parse_doc()`. `xpath` doesn't find any element - so `for`-loop doesn't run any `print()`. You should add extra `print()` at the beginning of `parse_doc()` to see when it was executed.

`xpath` may not find `class='Link--primary'` because this page uses `JavaScript` to add elements. And this may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and module `scrapy-selenium` to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`. `scrapy` has also [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) and [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to work with `JavaScript`.

(Doc: [Selecting dynamically-loaded content](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html))

---

Maybe `GitHub` has some API to get information without scraping.

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code which use `scrapy-selenium` and `Selenium 3`.

It doesn't work with `Selenium 4` because `scrapy-selenium` wasn't updated since 2020 and it doesn't work with newest `Selenium 4`

```
pip install scrapy-selenium
pip install 'selenium<4'
```

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#from shutil import which   # to run `which('firefox')` or `which('chrome')` in settings


repo_rule = Rule(
    LinkExtractor(
        restrict_xpaths="//a[@itemprop='name codeRepository']",
        restrict_text=r"ELTeC-.+"
    )
)

pagination_rule = Rule(
    LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='next_page']")
)

level_rule = Rule(
    LinkExtractor(allow=r"/level1"),
    follow=True,
    callback="parse_level"
)


class ELTecSpider(CrawlSpider):
    """Scrapy CrawlSpider for crawling the ELTec repo."""

    name = "eltec"
    start_urls = [
        "https://github.com/orgs/COST-ELTeC/repositories", 
        "https://github.com/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/tree/master/level1"
    ]

    rules = [
        repo_rule,
        pagination_rule,
        level_rule,
    ]

    def parse_level(self, response):
        print("\n>>> PARSE LEVEL:", response.url)
        #yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_docs, dont_filter=True)
        yield SeleniumRequest(url=response.url, callback=self.parse_docs, dont_filter=True, 
                wait_time=10,
                #wait_until=EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Link--primary'))
                wait_until=EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Link--primary'))
                )
        
    def parse_docs(self, response):
        print("\n>>> PARSE DOC:", response.url)
        
        docs_urls = response.selector.xpath("//a[@class='Link--primary']")
        #print("\n>>> LEN:", len(docs_urls))
        
        for url in docs_urls:
            text = url.xpath('.//text()').get()
            href = url.xpath('.//@href').get()
            #print("\n>>> INFO:", href, text)
            yield {"text": text, "url": href}
            
            
process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings={
        "FEEDS": {
            "items.json": {
                "format": "json",
                "overwrite": True
            },
        },
        
        'SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME': 'firefox',  # or 'chrome'
        'SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH': '/home/furas/bin/geckodriver',  # or which('geckodriver'), which('chromedrive')
        'SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS': ['-headless'],  # '--headless' if using `chrome` instead of `firefox`
        #'SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS': [],  # needs at least empty list

        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800},    
    }   
)

process.crawl(ELTecSpider)
process.start()
```

Result from `items.json`

```
[
{"text": "LIT00001_seinius_kuprelis.xml", "url": "/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/blob/master/level1/LIT00001_seinius_kuprelis.xml"},
{"text": "LIT00001_seinius_kuprelis.xml", "url": "/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/blob/master/level1/LIT00001_seinius_kuprelis.xml"},
{"text": "LIT00002_pietaris_algimantas.xml", "url": "/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/blob/master/level1/LIT00002_pietaris_algimantas.xml"},
{"text": "LIT00002_pietaris_algimantas.xml", "url": "/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/blob/master/level1/LIT00002_pietaris_algimantas.xml"},
{"text": "LIT00004_dobilas_bludas.xml", "url": "/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/blob/master/level1/LIT00004_dobilas_bludas.xml"},
{"text": "LIT00004_dobilas_bludas.xml", "url": "/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/blob/master/level1/LIT00004_dobilas_bludas.xml"},
{"text": "LIT00005_daukantas_zemaiciu_pasakos.xml", "url": "/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/blob/master/level1/LIT00005_daukantas_zemaiciu_pasakos.xml"},
{"text": "LIT00005_daukantas_zemaiciu_pasakos.xml", "url": "/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/blob/master/level1/LIT00005_daukantas_zemaiciu_pasakos.xml"},
{"text": "LIT00006_kudirka_virsininkai.xml", "url": "/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/blob/master/level1/LIT00006_kudirka_virsininkai.xml"},
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. You mentioned that the xpath call in `parse_docs` might be empty and you are correct. I tried it in the scrapy shell as well and the xpath call indeed returns empty. I wonder why though, at least the parts I am asking for are not dynamically created, also in the page source the links are there.

Comment: I turn off JavaScript in web browser (FIrefox) and reload some of the scraped page (ie. https://github.com/COST-ELTeC/ELTeC-lit/tree/master/level1) and it show me page without links to files (and without elements `class='Link--primary'`) - so it adds them using JavaScript. You may also check `response.body` or `response.text` in `parse_docs()` to see what HTML you get from server.

Comment: ok, thank you. Have you any idea how to still scrape this?

Comment: if you use [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) + [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  then you can use `SeleniumRequest()` instead of `Request()` and it will run web browser (`Firefox` or `Chrome`) to load page and run JavaScript code before you get full HTML. I will try to recreate working code to test it.

Comment: thank you for your kind help! I solved the task with the github api client for python in literally 4 functions. :D

Comment: I added full working code for `scrapy-selenium`. If you have working code for `github api` then you could add it as answer (and later you can accept and upvote your answer)